# PHP images displaying on website as broken, even though the URLs are valid (Discord.php)

Tags: php, html, api, discord, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

it's me again. I have a piece of code that was working yesterday, however it is now no longer displaying the images, they are coming up as 'broken' in the browser (the urls lead to valid locations, examples will be provided below). The purpose of this code is to query the Discord API, which then gets certain pieces of info from the snowflake and composes them into valid HTML tags, to reiterate this worked yesterday, no longer is.

This is how the images are displaying in the images I've created

[Broken Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0BMP.png)

Now if we take a look at my PHP (Some info redacted for security)

```
<?php

$json_options = [
  "http" => [
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Authorization: Bot API token"
  ]
];

$json_context = stream_context_create($json_options);

$json_get     = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/guildid/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context);

$json_decode  = json_decode($json_get, true);

$arr = array_filter($json_decode, function($e) {
  return in_array("role-id", $e['roles']);

});

foreach($arr as $e) {
  $uid = $e['user']['id']; $atar = $e['user']['avatar']; $uname = $e['user']['username']; $aimgurl = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/$uid/$atar.jpg";

  $count = $count + 1;
  echo "<img src='$aimgurl' alt=avatar$count' width='300' height='200' />";

}

?>
```

An example of the output would be a div like this:

```
<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/118715548849668096/505efab4aa33f882bab9ae22347bafa1.jpg" width="300" height="200">
```

Now if I manually visit the link https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/118715548849668096/505efab4aa33f882bab9ae22347bafa1.jpg, you'll see obviously the image is valid, but even when displaying on the blank PHP document (not on the webpage) the images still break. I thought at first perhaps there was javascript, or something conflicting with this, but I do believe this is not the case, and the root of the issue is how I am styling the image, or attempting to get it to display. However I am unaware of any other way to get an image onto my webpage with PHP without putting image tags, there is likely a way to do this. But if any of you have any words of advice, it'd be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should  try like `echo "<img src='"+$aimgurl+"' alt=avatar$count' width='300' height='200' />";`

Comment: what comes when you echo $aimgurl ?

Comment: If I echo "\n", $aimgurl @Sanjit it'll come up with a list of image urls (That are all valid)

Comment: @MayankVadiya if I use your code it comes up with 00000000 in the divs, so no go

Comment: Probably the image is protected. I have made a website where you need to load the original-Website to display the image. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @Bernhard you are right, I needed to do a base64 encode on it:

  $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($aimgurl));
  echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'">';

Comment: If you'd like to make your post an answer, feel free, and I'll mark it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It's okay, it was just a hint, you found the answer yourself :)

Comment: But answer the question yourself for helping other users :))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to mark my own post as an answer, I feel it's disrespectful to do so, as I appreciate the community and the help provided. Bernhard gave me the direction I needed to correct the issue, the problem was that I needed to encode the image with base64 before being able to display it. This is odd because it worked 100% fine yesterday, so it's odd that it didn't today. My best guess is that because I updated from PHP 5.x yesterday to PHP 7.x. Apologies as I know my code probably isn't perfect or beautiful. Hopefully this helps another new PHP user out there.

```
    <?php

    $json_options = [
      "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Authorization: Bot bot-token-here" //add your token
      ]
    ];

    $json_context = stream_context_create($json_options);

    $json_get     = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/guild-id-here/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context); //replace guild id

    $json_decode  = json_decode($json_get, true);

    $arr = array_filter($json_decode, function($e) {
      return in_array("role-id-to-find", $e['roles']); //replace role id

    });

foreach($arr as $e) {
  $uid = $e['user']['id']; $atar = $e['user']['avatar']; $uname = $e['user']['username']; $aimgurl = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/$uid/$atar.png";
  $count = $count +1;
  $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($aimgurl));
  echo 
  "<div class='usercontainer' style='position:relative;text-align:center;color:white;display:inline-block;font-size:10px;font-weight:900;z-index:1; overflow: auto;'>",
  "<style> .usercontainer img { width:60px;height:60px;border-radius:100%;padding:14px; } </style>",
  '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'" onerror=this.style.display="none">',
  "<div class='user' style='position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);font-family:'Raleway',Sans-Serif;'>",$uname,"</div>","</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you solved your problem with the above, then you should mark it as answered to make others know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Alrighty, I can't mark it resolved for 2 days, so I'll do so when I can :)